# Closed-form for $\sum_k r^{k^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Let $r \neq 1$. A finite geometric series
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1 - r} $$
is well-known and it has a nice closed-form. Let me modify the exponents of the summands from linear to quadratic.
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n r^{k^2} $$
*What is a closed-form for this series?* Surprisingly I find this quite challenging. Apparently, [WolframAlpha doesn't know what to do either](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Br%5E%28k%5E2%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+n%7D%5D). Part of the reason might be the series is no longer [hypergeometric](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricSeries.html). Does anyone know an answer? What if we admit a generating function $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n r^{k^2}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$ instead?

Comment: To be pedantic, the sum you posted *is* closed-form.

Comment: It is a partial sum of a theta series.

Comment: A [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520020/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-1-x-x4-x9x16x25-x) (surprisingly popular for *unknown* reason; see [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114329), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2737242), etc.)

Comment: @orlp I should have written 'with a bounded number of operations', to be pedantic.

Comment: @Gary, metamorphy: Thank you for your comments. I didn't notice but I would say it just rephrases by famous symbols and it doesn't answer my question. Perhaps it is popular because it looks elementary at first, has no standard name, and there is no definite answer.

Comment: There is no known closed form

Comment: @Orat (regarding your answer to @orlp) It can be debated whether or not computing x^n a bounded numer of operations. I grant you there is a fast algorithm.

Comment: Related: [A319015](http://oeis.org/A319015).

Comment: The fact that a question is asked 100 times and still doesn't have an answer *that you need* doesn't mean that it is OK to ask it 101th time. If you have an elaboration (such as a clarification of the "closed form" notion, or your generating-function idea), focus on that. And beware that multiple-questions-in-one are generally discouraged (there's a "need more focus" reason for closure).